# Changes in the httpd.conf file do not take affect after restarting the service

Tags: windows-server-2008, http, httpd.conf, websphere

I need to change the directory that is served up by the service. So I have changed the httpd.conf file:

```
# DocumentRoot "C:/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs/en_US"
DocumentRoot "C:/sites"

#<Directory "C:/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs/en_US">
<Directory "C:/sites">
```

But stopping and starting the service doesn't change the directory that is served up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the server to reload it's cache.

Answer (score -1):

In your configuration directory, look for the `sites-enabled` folder, in there should be a file called `000-default` or something similar; this is where you should be changing your document root. The settings in this file override the ones in `httpd.conf`.

This is where it is for Apache2, though I noticed you have your post tagged with IBM WebSphere. I have never deployed, or administered, WebSphere; this is mostly just a suggested place to look.

Comment: I think it's like most IBM tools... it's an open source project with a few IBM features to call there own.

Comment: Okay, sweet! In the directory where `httpd.conf` is kept, is there a `sites-enabled` directory?

Comment: There isn't. But I checked the server again today without making any changes. It's serving up the correct directory now. I must have been looking at a cache. :(

Comment: sites-enabled/ is unique to the debian-style packaging of Apache HTTP Server.